# Delete a SplitContainer without deleting other controls

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I can't believe I couldn't find the answer to this....

I no longer need to use a SplitContainer in my WinForms UI. But whenever I delete the SplitContainer, I lose all of my other controls too -- buttons, labels, textboxes, and charts. Anything that was in the SplitContainer is deleted as well. Very annoying.

What is the best way to remove a SplitContainer control but leave everything else in place?

Trivial Example:

[image]

Comment: Make room on your form and drag those controls into the empty space.  Alternatively, go to View - Other Windows - Document Outline and move the child controls out of the SplitContainer's hierarchy. Do not cut and paste since that will sever your event handlers.

Comment: just 1) copy the controls, 2) delete the container 3) click on form 4) paste the controls

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo Read my last sentence.

Comment: is setting the event handler so hard?

Comment: @LarsTech That worked. I never needed to use the Document Outline window in WinForms before now.

Comment: @LarsTech would you like to submit an answer? Both yours and Mehdi's ideas worked, and I figure you would like to get credit for the answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make room on your form and drag those controls into the empty space.

Alternatively, go to View - Other Windows - Document Outline and move the child controls out of the SplitContainer's hierarchy.

[image]

Do not cut and paste since that will sever your event handlers.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Thanks!